# tmux ignoring path given with -c flag on split-window & new-window

Tags: bash, tmux

Using `split-window` & `new-window` in tmux to create new panes & windows seems to be ignoring any use of the `-c` (start-directory) flag.

I've tried binding this to `%` in my `~/.tmux.conf` & manually entering it as a command inside tmux at the prompt by hitting `prefix :`.

My intention is to set it to always use my current $PWD by binding the keys like this:

```
unbind %
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

unbind '"'
bind '"' split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

but it doesn't seem to matter what argument I pass to `-c`, tmux just opens the new pane or window at my home directory.

I'm running tmux v2.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 accessed via ssh. Here's the contents of my `/home/andrew/.tmux.conf` file:

```
# bind new panes to same path as active pane

# horizontal split
unbind %
bind % split-window -h -c "/home/andrew/dev/py-spec" # I've also tried "#{pane_current_path}" here as well, but neither works

# vertical split
unbind '"'
bind   '"' split-window -v -c "/home/andrew/dev/py-spec" # I've also tried "#{pane_current_path}" here as well, but neither works
```

Comment: These bindings are working fine for me! what version of `tmux` are you using? I'm on v2.6.

Comment: `$ tmux -V` returns `tmux 2.6`, so we're the same version. I'm accessing the ubuntu computer with tmux on it over ssh; could that somehow make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't... unless you're unable to type `%` and `"` correctly.

Comment: I've tried `bind-key` as well; I can't even get it to recognize anything when I manually give the `split-window -h -c '/some/path/here'` command in the prompt too by hitting `Ctrl-B`, then `:`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using. Sorry, I wasn't sure what syntax to say I was using that key combination.

Comment: Entering `^B`, `?` should show you a list of the current bindings... can you use that to confirm that `^B`, `:` is bound to `command-prompt`, and that your others are taking effect?

Comment: output from `^B`, `?`: `bind-key    -T prefix       C-b               send-prefix`. It's also correctly loading the split-window binding I'm trying to edit in my .tmux.conf: `bind-key    -T prefix       %                 split-window -h -c /home/andrew/dev/py-spec`

Comment: Is that the only line output? I have 171 lines of output from `^B`, `?`... Now that we've confirmed it's loading your config correctly, can you confirm that you can type `%` and `"` correctly? (I suspect you can...)

Comment: I have many other lines as well, those are the two that looked relevant. `%` & `"` both work to create new panes as they should. I've added my `.tmux.conf` to the question above in case that helps as well.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured out my problem, I'm putting it here just in case if anyone else makes the same mistake I did.

Turns out my .bashrc was always changing the directory back to home here:

```
# reset current directory to $HOME
cd
```

I have no idea why I ever stuck that line in there, but removing it fixed the problem.

Thanks to @Attie for all the help troubleshooting!